# Algorithms based on signal handling and systems are acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

In my case, I want to ask about IIR, but as algorthim and the math involved in it, not as circuits.

Is it OK to ask about it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you'll probably get better answers on [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hm, never saw this SE site, thanks!